# Django - how to get the field value before saving?

Tags: python, django, models

I'm new with Django and
I've been trying to get the value from a model field before I save it, for example:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, primary_key=True)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=50, null=False)


def print_name():
    #here I want to catch and print the student's name before it saves
```

I read about the pre_save method, but I still can't manage how to get the current name.

Answer (score 2):

Just override the `save` method inside your model.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, primary_key=True)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=50, null=False)

    def save(self):
        print self.name
        super(Student, self).save()
```

Comment: Thanks! so with this, I can concatenate two (or more) of the fields and generate, let say a code with the current field Im saving: 

   def save(self):
         student_code = self.name + str(self.id)
         code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = False, default= student_code)
                super(Student, self).save()

Comment: ya, but you must specify the resultant field in your model class. `code = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = False)` on your save it would be, `self.code =  self.name + str(self.id);  super(Student, self).save() `

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, none of the answers worked for me.

I was still able to solve the problem by retrieving the object from the database and comparing it against the version being saved:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    old_object_instance = YourModel.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
    if old_object_instance.your_value != self.your_value:
        do_something_here()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, previous answers could or could not work.

If you use this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self.name)
    super(self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This only will work if your are editing a previously saved object. If you are creating a new object and want to get a field value before saving, you need to do this (will also work in case you are editing).

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self._meta.get_field('name').value_from_object(self))
    super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by overriding the default `save` method like this.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, primary_key=True)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=50, null=False)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print self.name
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter if it's in `save()` method or in any other method within the model class, you can access any model attribute with `self` which refers to the current instance:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, primary_key=True)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=50, null=False)

    def any_function(self, any_arg1, any_arg2):
       ...  
       print self.name
       return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i give you another solution using [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-save) Signal

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=YourModel)
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    print instance.name
```

Comment: can we also get session data into pre_save??